# Eclipse Javascript development with VJET

Tags: eclipse, nodes, vjet

Using Eclipse Juno with VJet

Can you create typelib from javascripts yourself?

I know you can download jquery and a few others from: http://www.ebayopensource.org/p2/vjet/typelib/

But obviously you will need others.

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes type libraries are just JavaScript files which use VJETDoc and VJOJS to define types for

object literals using vjo.otype
functions which do not change Function definition vjo.otype
functions which have additional properties using vjo.ftype
methods of a class using vjo.ctype 
globals which can be define using a .globals section.
and more...

Many type libraries are located under this github address

https://github.com/ebayopensource/vjet-typelib

More info about VJETDoc[1] and VJOJS[2] and type library tutorial[3]

[1]http://www.ebayopensource.org/wiki/display/VJET/VJETDoc+Quick+Reference
[2]http://www.ebayopensource.org/wiki/display/VJET/Semantic+Comparison+-+Java+and+VJET+VJO
[3]http://www.ebayopensource.org/wiki/display/VJET/VJET+Type+lib+Tutorial+-+part+1